# item's color in drawer_layout in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, colors, drawerlayout

I am trying to figure out how can I use the original colors of the items listed in a drawer layout. After running the applications all the icons are displayed in gray colors and lost their original colors!
Do you know how can I fix it? and the problem might due to which part?

This is what I designed and see in design view , and actually I want the result exactly like this:

[image]

And this is what is shown during run time :
[image]

Comment: Problem is not just with the icons, also the texts look weird. Can you provide the xml layout for your drawer layout? And also the java code, only if you have interacted with the drawer through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add code navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); as below:

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Hope to help you!

Answer (score 1):

**Do you know how can I fix it? and the problem might due to which part?**

> please remove this from `ItemIconTint` as done below

**From XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black" 
    ... />
```

**Programmatically**

```
yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: your answer also is correct. and thanks. just because our friend's answer is correct as yours but posted sooner I accepted that one. anyway appreciate :)

Comment: That's allright. will try giving answer sooner @Jasmine